# How effective is the "Photonix Core"?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I discovered the "Photonix Core" in *No Man's Sky* and for the most part it appears to be the third and final tier (essentially Theta level) of the technology.

Per the [Photonix Core](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Photonix_Core) wiki, it is describes it as

> Photonix Core is the third upgrade available for the Pulse Engine.

However doing some more digging, the [Pulse Engine](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Pulse_Engine) page is telling different story on it's tier level

> **Upgrade progression**
>
> - Pulse Jet Sigma / Photonix Core
> - Pulse Jet Tau

The *Photonix Core* is shown on the same level as *Pulse Jet Sigma* and both require the same materials to install the technology; being **100 Chrysonite**, **200 Iron**, & **50 Zinc**

As the *Photonix Core* and *Pulse Jet Sigma* appear to be equal, how effective will the *Photonix Core* be in addition to the other engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [wikia](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Photonix_Core),

> This upgrade shares the same crafting cost as the Pulse Jet Sigma but they are not the same.
>
> Photonix Core provides additional attributes over the "Pulse Jet Sigma"; it is one of several technologies available only for pre-ordered players.

Additionally, [this observation](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4xnzcf/what_is_a_photonix_core_and_why_is_it_named/d6gzxud) seems to indicate that there is a functional difference between Pulse Jet Sigma and Photonix Core.

> I have all three and it behaves exactly the way "pulse drive theta" would have.

Comment: Ah yes, I was just reading part of the article as you posted your answer. I feel like I should probably re-take reading 101

Comment: I am the worst RTFC offender, no worries.